# How do I put things above an mx:HTML element?

Tags: apache-flex, air, z-index

How do I put things above an mx:HTML element? No matter where I place the code it's always under the `<mx:HTML>` element. Can this even be done?

Example:

```
<mx:Canvas x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="#ff0099"/>
<mx:Label x="150" y="50" color="#ffffff" text="CAN YOU SEE ME?"/>    
<mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" location="http://www.google.com/"/>
<mx:Canvas x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="#ff0099"/>
<mx:Label x="150" y="50" color="#ffffff" text="CAN YOU SEE ME?"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above works perfectly fine. In AbsoluteLayout, things are added in order and hence first and second item are hidden behind the bigger HTML. But the Canvas and Label afterwards are very much visible on top of HTML. Run and see it yourself with the below code sample (mostly yours):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:Panel>
        <mx:Canvas x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="#ff0099"/>
        <mx:Label x="150" y="50" color="#000000" text="CAN YOU SEE ME?"/>    
        <mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" location="http://www.google.com/"/>
        <mx:Canvas x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" backgroundColor="#ff0099"/>
        <mx:Label x="150" y="50" fontSize="32" color="#654321" text="CAN YOU SEE ME?"/>

    </s:Panel>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: You're right, it **does** work in Flex.

In my situation it didn't work because I was displaying a video embed inside the HTML element but that embed didn't have `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`. I should've tested it with Google and I would've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally the elements are rendered in the order they're added in the container. From my test, the canvas and label you have after the HTML element are displayed over it, but the text is displayed with white color (color="#ffffff"), so you won't see it because of that...